# LSTM with keras/tensorflow implementation

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm trying to learn a sufficient statistic from data. My input are sequences of samples `x_samples` which are real numbers. The length of the input sequence varies and has no fixed value. There is no memory between the sequences - each sequence is completely independent from all the others.

The output `y` is the sufficient statistic given by the sum of `log(p_1(x)/p_2(x))` for all the samples in a given sequence (thus a RNN is needed). `p_1` and `p_2` are two unknown functions (they are the PDFs of some process). For example if a sequence has 3 samples `x1,x2,x3` the output is given by `y = log(p_1(x1)/p_2(x1)) + log(p_1(x2)/p_2(x2)) + log(p_1(x3)/p_2(x3))`.

I am wondering how to input the sequences into my network. I've seen a few solutions to this problem but none of them seem relevant for me.

- I don't want to use zero padding. The reason is that the sequence has no maximum length - it depends on other factors independent of this problem and may theoretically take any value. The LSTM is part of a bigger RL system. The data is generated along the way  so i don't have a fixed data set.
- I don't want to use 1 hot encoding for my input since `x_samples` are just real values. It is possible to quantize the input but i think this is a bad solution.

I think it makes sense to input the the samples one by one with a start and end tokens for each sequence. Does this make sense?

Additionally I wonder if during the training I should reset the memory of the LSTM in the end of each sequence (with `model.reset_states()`, have I understood it correctly?) or it is enough to set a start and end tokens in the begging and the end of every sequence.